# Smarter company/auto-complete

Tags: company-mode, auto-complete-mode, gtags

I have moved to Emacs due to its diversity and yes...it simply Rocks! I have one final thing to resolve. I mostly program in python and it is a great feature to auto complete a function with its parentheses and the arguments "pre-entered", then just tab through them to fill in the right variables. Also what I really like is the documentation pop-up while auto completing. The last desired feature is the function lookup in a library (eg. `os.path.j` will find `join`) I have achieved all features: documentation pop-up and library function lookup via Jedi or Anaconda. The function completion with parentheses and arguments via Gtags. The problem is this:

[image: company popup with jedi and gtags]

The top line is from Gtags (full auto complete with parentheses and arguments, no documentation pop-up). The second line is from Jedi (documentation, but no full auto complete). I have been searching the web for several hours with no luck so far.

The question is: can Company or Auto-complete be smarter about it and realize that they have the same function completion data and merge them into a single line providing documentation and full completion? Thus providing a smarter and better user experience?

Sub-question: Is there a way to store all the gtags files generated per project all in one place, rather than those files existing in every project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding argument expansion, you should file a feature request at [company-jedi](https://github.com/syohex/emacs-company-jedi) (or [company-anaconda](https://github.com/proofit404/company-anaconda)!).

And about files generated by `gtags`, I don't think you want that. You'll have to teach every tool that uses them about the "one place" directory. But setting `GTAGSLIBPATH` might help with that.

Comment: Thanks for an answer, that is very helpful. So basically at this stage there is no feature for Python to have a argument expansion and docs at the same time (in one line I mean, like semantic in c++) ?

Comment: Not to my knowledge, at least.

Comment: Oh! And thanks for the Ggtags tip. That is indeed a fair point.